# intToBits() to convert integer64 to bits and store in new variable

Tags: r

Below is the example data frame. Variable rebounds contains integer64 values. I want to create new column i.e, convert intTobits  and store in new variable.

```
df <- data.frame(team=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
             points=c(99, 90, 86, 88, 95),
             rebounds=c(2317414400, 3928023040, 1788928000, 24, 28))

 
intaddVar <- function(int_df){
  addintRes <- intToBits(int_df)%>%rev%>%as.integer%>%paste(collapse = '')
  return(addintRes)
}

df %>% mutate(intVar = if("team" %in% colnames(.)) intaddVar(.data[["rebounds"]]) else NULL)
```

Current output
df$intVar

```
[1] "0000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000110111111000000000000000000100110010111000000000000000000000000100100001101"
[2] "0000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000110111111000000000000000000100110010111000000000000000000000000100100001101"
[3] "0000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000110111111000000000000000000100110010111000000000000000000000000100100001101"
[4] "0000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000110111111000000000000000000100110010111000000000000000000000000100100001101"
[5] "0000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000110111111000000000000000000100110010111000000000000000000000000100100001101"
```

Expected output of df$intVar

```
 [1] "10000000000000000000000000000000"
 [2] "10000000000000000000000000000000"
 [3] "01101010101000001110000000000000"
 [4] "00000000000000000000000000011000"
 [5] "00000000000000000000000000011100"
```

Any suggestions on what is going on here?

I also see below warnings

```
 Warning message:
 In intToBits(int_df) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote your `intaddVar` function it is not vectorized. That is if you pass in multiple values you get only one out; it does not preserve the length of the input.

A quick fix is to use the `Vectorize` function

```
intaddVar <- Vectorize(function(int_df){
  intToBits(int_df) %>% rev %>% as.integer %>% paste(collapse = '')
})
```